# How do I implement this class correctly?

Tags: java, interface

As a homework assignment, we have to implement an attached class- SortedList- and implement it with a linked binary Search/Sort tree.

Here is the class heading of the interface (given by the teacher):

```
public interface SortedListInterface<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
```

And here is when I implement it:

```
public class BinaryTree<T> implements SortedListInterface<T> {
```

The error comes up as : `Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>> of the type 
 SortedListInterface<T>`

How can I fix this? As of now I can't test my class because of this error and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Since it's homework, I won't provide a direct answer, but I'll give you a hint: The type parameter T in the SortedListInterface demands to be extending Comparable. Your class declaration must reflect this restriction.

Comment: `public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements SortedListInterface<T>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're passing `T` as the type parameter to `SortedListInterface`, it must meet the bounds specified by `SortedListInterface`.  But you haven't specified any bounds for your `T` that you declared on `BinaryTree`, hence the error.

Specify the same bounds for `T` in `BinaryTree` that exist for `T` in `SortedListInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

T is a generic type. If you are going to keep using a generic type in your implementation, you need to use the same bounds as found in your interface.

### Like so:

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements SortedListInterface<T> {
```